# How to use Urban Airship Deep link with PHP

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, deep-linking, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to implement deep link messaging using [Urban Airship PHP libraray](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/php/) , but I cannot find documentation nor relevant code.
right now I have this

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use UrbanAirship\Airship;
use UrbanAirship\AirshipException;
use UrbanAirship\UALog;
use UrbanAirship\Push as P;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

$droidToken = "my-device-token" ;

UALog::setLogHandlers(array(new   StreamHandler("php://stdout",Logger::INFO)));
$airship = new Airship("key", "Secret");

    $req = $airship->push()
          ->setAudience(P\apid($droidToken))
          ->setMessage(P\message("This is the title",
               "<html><body><h1>This is the message</h1></body></html>",
               "text/html",
               "utf-8",
               array("value"=>"agh://myAppName.app/preferences23")))
          ->setDeviceTypes(P\all);
        $response = $req->send();
```

where `agh://myAppName.app` is the template and  `preferences23` should be the value

I [understand](http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua.html#action-mappings) I need to add it in an `actions` tag:

```
{
   "actions": {
      "open": {
         "type": "deep_link",
         "content": "prefs"
      }
   }
}
```

but where?

When I run the code above, I receive the message in my phone, but, message has no deep link in it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it !
You just need to add an `action` to the notification structure

`type:` deep_link, 
 `content:` is the deep link url.

```
$req = $airship->push()
       ->setAudience(P\apid($deviceToken))
       ->setNotification(P\notification("my message',
                                         array("actions" => array(
                                                   "open" => array(
                                                      "type" => "deep_link",
                                                      "content" => "js://myapp.app/deepLink" 
                                                    )))))
       ->setDeviceTypes(P\all);
```

Comment: From where we can find it "js://myapp.app/deepLink"?

Comment: from where i can find out deep link url for content key?